# Memory consumption of node.js process increases constantly

Tags: node.js, express

I made a simple web server using express:

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();

var route = express.Router();
route.get('/foo', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.url);
    res.json(200, {'status':'OK'});
});

app.use('/api', route);
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.listen(8080);
```

I have a client running which does every second a GET request to the server.

If I look at the node process it started with 16 MB size.
After 14 hours it's already at 50 MB size and is still slowly increasing.

I started the node process with:

```
node server.js --max-old-space-size 1
```

I use node 0.10.29 and express 4.5.1.

The webserver should run 24x7 on a Raspi and I'm afraid, that after some weeks I get Out Of Memory.

Comment: I'm not a node expert unfortunately, but as any javascript code, you should definitely profile it and see what part of your code is causing this memory leakage

Comment: That's why you normally don't run servers 24x7. You use a tool to restart it after some time or some amount of requests. As for your problem: I haven't experienced it. I believe that it can't be Node.js itself causing it. Possibly it's Express. Maybe you should ask Express developers?

Comment: Memory leak, check for profiler in Google Chrome and inspect the leaks

Comment: I use express which is THE most used web server in node!

Comment: I'm new to node, and I'm not interested in profiling such a widely used library like express. I just want to have a simple STABLE small web server.
Maybe I have to look for another language which provides that.

Comment: "python -m http.server"  seems to be better.
Memory consumption stable for over 4 hours now.